# Application cache, failing to load resources

Tags: html, caching

I have this small problem that I can't really understand why it's happening. The caching is working properly as expected, but when I refresh the page, external links like font awesome etc.. are not being loaded  And I get the following errors every time
[image]

The **cache.appcache:**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2015-12-24 v1.0.0
css/main.css
css/bootstrap.css
css/responsive.css
css/news.css
img/logo.png
js/bootstrap.min.js
js/jquery.js
js/pace.js

NETWORK:
sign_up.php
contact.php
```

Answer (score 1):

**FIXED:**

Turns out what I did was a really noob mistake.

The NETWORK section lists all URLs that may be loaded over the Internet. If the application includes any API calls etc, make sure to enumerate them there.

**The fix:**

```
NETWORK:
*
```

> Files listed in this section may come from the network if they aren't
>   in the cache, otherwise the network isn't used, even if the user is
>   online. You can white-list specific URLs here, or simply " * ", which
>   allows all URLs. Most sites need " * ".